# random.choice in python, uniform distribution of elements

Tags: python, random

I have written a function in python which generate dictionaries in this format:

{"A":20,"T":20,"G":30,"C":30}
I want each value to be generated in a range of GC 40%-60%

```
def makeDict(gcRange, min):
     maxC = gcRange[1]-min
     probC = random.choice(np.arange(min, maxC, 2))
     gc = [gcRange[0]-probC, gcRange[1]-probC]
     probG = random.choice(np.arange(gc[0], gc[1], 2))
     at = 100 - probC - probG
     probA = at/2
     probT = at/2
     return({"A":probA, "T":probT, "G":probG, "C":probC})
d=[]
for i in range(1,1000):
    d.append(makeDict([40,60],10))
```

I understand that the random.choise occurs with replacement and random.sample occurs without replacement. I want it to be with replacement since I am going to generate 1000 dictionaries.
However, when I generate the 1000 dictionaries in my loop, I want to have a uniform distribution of those values that were randomly chosen.
Is that already occurring in the random.choice function or do I need to set the weights? If yes, how ? in the function or in the for loop?
also, why if I do print(len(d)) it will show 999 instead that 1000?
In addition, sometimes I do get negative values.why?

Comment: It shows 999 instead of 1000 because of the range you use. e.g. range(1, 5) is 1,2,3,4 -> len 4. The end of range is **not** included

Comment: Also, do not use *min* as a variable name. It overwrites the built-in function min and can cause issues

Comment: I see, but in other cases when I do  "for in in range(1,10):" it will show len is 10, I was wondering why...

Comment: ok I change the min to something else

Comment: probably the reason why I was getting negative values in the dictionary is because of the min

Comment: are there cases when the end of the range is included and cases when the end of the range is not included?

Comment: For the range you likely want to use just range(1000) which is 0-999, then the length is 1000. Also it seems unlikely that the negative values were caused by the min i *think* it's use should cause any issues here

Comment: I am a bit new to Python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232503/discussion-between-ondrej-bastar-and-paolo-lorenzini).

Comment: I think it was because of min, now I am trying many times, and I do not see those negative values any longer, any other thing that might cause that?

Comment: @OndřejBaštař also, do you have any comments about the random.choice?

Comment: You can use `random.choices()`. [reference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choices)

Comment: yes, I know, but how to obtain a uniform distribution in the for loop with the makeDict function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, sometimes, you could obtain a negative value. It's normal.

- gcRange = [40,60] and mini = 10 (replace min by mini)
- maxC = gcRange[1]-mini // maxC = 50
- probC = random.choice(np.arange(mini, maxC, 2)) // probC could take 50 (maxC)
- gc = [gcRange[0]-probC, gcRange[1]-probC] // gc = [40-50, 60 -50] = [-10, 10]
- probG = random.choice(np.arange(gc[0], gc[1], 2)) // so probG could be negative

Comment: I see, so I guess I need to eliminate those dictionaries where there are negative values